# ¿Traducción para "Whack a mole"?

Tags: solicitud-de-modismo

Hay una expresión que oigo mucho en el trabajo que es

> This is like playing *[whac a mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whac-A-Mole)*

Whac-A-Mole es (o era) un juego de arcade (aunque he visto similares en ferias) en el que unos topos salen de sus agujeros en la mesa de juego y tienes que golpearlos con un mazo antes de que se vuelvan a esconder.

El sentido del modismo es describir una de estas situaciones donde de repente se surgen varias cosas a la vez que atender, y cuando terminas una parece que salen otras tantas nuevas. Por eso te encuentras de repente, como en el juego, dando frenéticos mazazos a ver si consigues terminar cuantas más cosas mejor.

Whac-A-Mole derivó en un par de juegos de mesa (o de "alfombra" incluso, de MB si no recuerdo mal) que por lo menos en España fueron traducidos como "guacamole" (pierde el significado del original de "Machaca-un-topo" pero conserva la sonoridad del vocablo original" "guacamole" vs "whac-a-mole").

¿Hay alguna expresión o modismo en español que tenga el mismo sentido de "surgen problemas nuevos tan rápidamente que casi no podemos asignarles prioridades y estamos intentando solucionarlos al vuelo"?

Comment: Sí que la hay: "¡Dios mío, esto es un infierno!" (dicho con la voz de Rambo). :-)

Comment: ¿Te vale "a destajo"?

Comment: The game is similar to Elmer Fudd's difficulties catching Bugs Bunny, who would always pop up saying Nya-nya from some other rabbit hole.  Is Bugs Bunny well enough known among Spanish speakers?  Another thing it's similar to is the idea of being too busy running around putting out fires to be able to solve underlying problems.  Is there an idiom for that?

Comment: yes @aparente001 we use the same and I think that is a good idea for an answer.  Putting out fires = apagando incendios.

Comment: Es como jugar al gato y al ratón (??)

Comment: @fernando.reyes, sí, hlecuanda tiene una respuesta usando ese modismo, pero creo que el significado es más "una persecución interminable" que el "esto parece una _hidra_" (que por cierto me sorprende que nadie haya mencionado todavía...)

Comment: En Chile puede ser "_arar el mar_".

Answer (score 6):

Una expresión muy habitual es *no dar abasto*. Se usa cuando los problemas o tareas aparecen a un ritmo mayor al que puedes manejar. Es menos colorista que la inglesa, pero muy usada.

> No doy abasto para atender a todos los clientes.
>
> El servicio de atención al cliente no daba abasto con tantas quejas.

Comment: +1 Una traducción perfectamente idiomática, de hecho está en el DRAE. No se necesitan metáforas ni cultura pop.

Comment: Ah, I was close to figuring it out. I thought that meant the subject was unwilling to help, but it makes more sense meaning the problem can't be contained. From Relato de un Náufrago : "Cuando llegamos a la larga callecita de Mulatos la policía no dio abasto para contener la multitud."

Answer (score 2):

No se me ocurre una expresión que sea igual de corta y que no precise de más aclaraciones:

> Esto es como jugar a los marcianitos: por muchos que mates siempre vienen más.

La palabra "marcianitos" obviamente no viene en la RAE. Aquí en España se usó cuando el *boom* de las máquinas recreativas ("ya está el niño jugando a los marcianitos"), sobre todo debido a las primeras tipo *[Space Invaders](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Invaders)*. A partir de ahí se denominaba así a casi cualquier máquina recreativa, o incluso a aquellas máquinas tipo *[Game & Watch](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_%26_Watch)* de los años 80, que también ofrecían un sistema de juego que se repetía sin final.

Ejemplos:

> *La idea de competitividad está tan extendida, que Juanito, quien ante una máquina de "marcianitos" afirmaba "no me gusta perder ni a las canicas", tenía un monumental enfado, medio simulado, medio en serio, al terminar el encuentro.*
>
> Artículo de ABC, 18/05/1982: "Hoy se entrenarán en Valencia, tras el viaje".
>
> ---
>
> *Añadió que esperaba que los ordenadores sirvieran para algo más que para que los funcionarios jugaran a los marcianitos.*
>
> Artículo de ABC, 15/04/1989: "Definitivo: Entre 1.700 y 2.000 contratados a dedo se convertirán en funcionarios".

Al menos en España, las máquinas de tipo Whac-A-Mole no son muy conocidas, al menos por ese nombre. Alguna se ve en algún salón recreativo, pero la gente seguramente las conocerá como "la máquina esa de aporrear bichos". Al no haber tenido mucho éxito no tiene un nombre popular por el que ser identificada.

Answer (score 1):

Una expresión con sentido similar es "Jugando al gato y al ratón", en el sentido que es una cacería infructuosa que nunca acabará, pues el ratón siempre logra escabullirse.

Se usa en México cuando por ejemplo​; llamas por teléfono a un cliente,  y no se encuentra disponible. Dejas tu número y recado en el correo de voz. Cuando el cliente te devuelve la llamada, ahora tú estás ocupado! El cliente deja recado en tu buzón . Cuando por fin logran coincidir, el comentario *"Caramba, parece que estamos jugando al gato y al ratón"* es apropiada para describir la situación.

Comment: No es una posibilidad mala, pero sugiere una relación "uno a uno" con el número de problemas y quien debe hacer se cargo de ellos. En "whac-a-mole" hay mucho problemas y una persona o equipo encargado de ellos.

Comment: Curioso, @Diego, pues siempre imaginé que en *whack-a-mole* se trataba de un solo topo asomándose por diversos agujeros en una red de túneles, lo que haría de esta expresión la más cercana pero se me ocurrió orltra posibilidad en mi segunda respuesta

Answer (score 1):

En Argentina se suele hablar de "incendios" y de "estar incendiados" o "vivir (constantemente) incendiado", implicando que como en un incendio forestal, surgen focos de incendio por todos lados, y mientras uno apaga un arbusto, otro se enciende en otro lado.

También, para realzar la cualidad netamente reactiva de la situación solemos decir "estamos siempre corriendo de atrás" (como persiguiendo a alguien o algo que se escapa en vez de estar esperándolo más adelante en su camino).

No sé si alguna de estas expresiones es de uso común en otras regiones...

Answer (score 1):

Una expresión idiomática tremendamente hispánica (aunque tal vez sea *políticamente incorrecta* hoy en día) y  que tiene el sentido de enfrentarse a una tarea de nunca acabar en la que uno solo se enfrenta a una multitud de problemas podría ser

> ***Es como amar a Dios en tierra de indios***

también supone una tarea titánica o de gran dificultad. Está expresión viene de las dificultades que encontraron los insulares en la cristianización del nuevo mundo durante la conquista, o más universalmente "el *intercambio Colombino*"

La traducción al inglés más aséptica podría ser ***It's like loving God while living in a Heathen's country*** (Amar a Dios en un país de herejes) aunque no deja de ser potencialmente ofensiva, pues dejando de lado el racismo de *indios* no deja de implicar que es ambos interlocutores son cristianos.

Comment: Interesante modismo. No lo conocía. +1

Comment: Es uno de mis modismos favoritos! de cierta manera forma parte de la experiencia hispanoamericana. Nuestros vecinos al norte, no tuvieron dificultad en amar a Dios en estas tierras, simplemente arrasaron con los nativos. En contraste, la Reina Isabel decreto que todo indígena en el nuevo mundo era súbdito de la corona, lo que de entrada daba igualdad ante la ley a los Insulares y nativos. Matar a un indígena era homicidio, y contraer nupcias con ellos no se consideraba "bestialidad" lo que derivó en el mestizaje colonial y todos los contratiempos para *amar a Dios* de este lado del charco!

Answer (score 1):

Yo usaría la referencia clásica a la Hidra: le cortan una cabeza y le salen dos.

Answer (score 0):

Mi sugerencia para la interpretación de "whack a mole" sería simplemente "**un juego de nunca acabar**".